# Can't access polymorphic association from test, but can from browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Note the two `puts` lines in the method. When accessed by `followers`, the result is empty, whereas when accessed by `Follower.all`, the result contains one or more expected objects.

How can this be?

**book.rb (model)**

```
has_many :followers, as: :followable, dependent: :destroy

def followed_by_user?(user)
    puts "--- followers: #{followers.inspect}"       # EMPTY
    puts "--- Follower.all: #{Follower.all.inspect}" # contains expected user
    followers.map{|l| l.user_id}.include?(user.id)   # returns false
end
```

Comment: Since the title of your question suggests that the context for your problem is a test, please show your test setup.

Comment: I figured this out when I began preparing the edit to this post. I added test setup and output, and then decided to also add a Rails console example - and that's when I realized the problem. All this time in the Rails console I was calling `followers` on a freshly fetched object - and it was only when I added another follower and ran `followers` again only to see the old ("cached") result. So I ran `reload` on the object, and then ran `followers` and obtained the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

There's no logical contradiction. The first `puts` shows the followers associated with *this* instance of a User; the second `puts` is showing *all* of the followers, including ones that are associated with other Users.

So it's perfectly reasonable for the first set to be empty and the second set to be non-empty.

Comment: Thanks for your time in trying to help me. I figured it out (see comment to my question). Respectfully, I think you should probably delete this answer so that you don't get a down-vote by some passerby.